# How to stop the maven-release-plugin from using an old version of the maven-gpg-plugin

Tags: java, maven

How can I configure the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) to use version 1.6 of the maven-gpg-plugin in my `pom.xml`?

When I run `mvn release:prepare`, the maven-release-plugin (version 2.5.3) is executing a sub-process that uses a very old version of the maven-gpg-plugin (1.1):

```
$ mvn release:prepare
...
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) @ heroku-sdk-parent ---
...
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
...
    [INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.1:sign (sign-artifacts) @ heroku-sdk-parent ---
```

Eventually this gives me an error because the maven-gpg-plugin:1.1 doesn't work with the gpg 2.2.4 on my machine.  Nothing I've tried has worked.

You can find the actual project I'm working with here:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-maven-plugin

You can reproduce with:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/heroku/heroku-maven-plugin
$ cd heroku-maven-plugin
$ ./mvnw release:prepare -DdryRun
```

Comment: Define the version of the maven-gpg-plugin in a pluginManagement area of your pom...best would that be done in a parent pom wich is used by other projects as well...

Comment: I've tried putting version 1.6 in pluginManagement, but the sub-process still uses 1.1

Comment: Did you check your Maven settings?

Comment: Please show the pom file you are using...

Comment: It's linked in the desc https://github.com/heroku/heroku-maven-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my use of a deprecated [oss-parent pom from Sonatype](https://github.com/sonatype/oss-parents).

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
  <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
  <version>9</version>
</parent>
```

I removed this, and my build started working.